# Check if an user is in a database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have developed a game with Javascript and when the user finishes it, I must save his record in a database. Here you see the code:

```
$temp = $_POST['playername'];             //username
$text  = file_get_contents('names.txt');  //list with all usernames

//this text file contains the names of the players that sent a record.

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","username","pass","my_mk7vrlist");

if (stripos(strtolower($text), strtolower($temp)) !== false) {
//if the username is in the list, don't create a new record but edit the correct one   

 mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE `my_mk7vrlist`.`mk7game` SET `record` = '".$_POST['dadate']."' WHERE `mk7game`.`playername` = ".$temp." LIMIT 1 ");

} else {

 //The username is not in the list, so this is a new user --> add him in the database
 mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO `mk7game` (`playername`,`record`,`country`,`timen`) VALUES ('".$_POST['playername']."', '".$_POST['dadate']."', '".$_POST['country']."', '".$_POST['time_e']."')");

 file_put_contents("names.txt",$text."\n".$temp);
 //update the list with this new name
}

//Close connection
mysqli_close($con);
```

When I have a new user (the part inside my "else") the code works correctly because I have a new row in my database.

When the username already exists in the list, it means that this player has already sent his record and so I must update the table. By the way I cannot edit the record on the player that has alredy sent the record.

```
mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE `my_mk7vrlist`.`mk7game` SET `record` = '".$_POST['dadate']."' WHERE `mk7game`.`playername` = ".$temp." LIMIT 1 ");
```

It looks like this is wrong, and I can't get why. I am pretty new with PHP and MySQL.

Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: I'm going to cry a little bit inside. 1) Put the names *in* the database 2) Use placeholders 3) Handle errors.

Comment: Why are you using `stripos` then `strtolower` when `stripos` is case insensitive? And searching for `chuck` will also find `chuckles`

Comment: make a unique key on username then use https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: @Class As I said, I am pretty new with PHP and MySQL. I have found stripos reading the online documentation.

Comment: having `!== false` is unnecessary, try removing it

Comment: @Arian No, it's necessary. If the match is at position `0`, `stripos` will return 0, which is falsy.

Comment: try to run your update query in your sql database to see if it works

Comment: Sidenote: I take it that you carefully hid your `.txt` file and protecting it using `.htaccess`

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yes I did, it's protected

Comment: @Barmar oops you are right... my mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing quotes around `$temp` in the `UPDATE` statement:

```
mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE `my_mk7vrlist`.`mk7game` 
                    SET `record` = '".$_POST['dadate']."' 
                    WHERE `mk7game`.`playername` = '".$temp."' 
                                                   ^         ^
                    LIMIT 1 ") or die(mysqli_error($con));
```

However, it would be better to make use of prepared statements with parameters, rather than inserting strings into the query.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't notice it :)

Comment: You should also check for errors and report the error message, that might have helped you "notice" it.

Comment: Gonna accept your answer, your solution worked. Just another thing: do you think that I sould improve `if (stripos(strtolower($text), strtolower($temp)) !== false)` somehow when I look for duplicates in my database?

Comment: Why are you using a file, and not checking the database itself?

Comment: Your test can also produce false positives. If there's a user `foobar` and you search for `foo`, it will say there's a match.

Comment: I am learning PHP and MySQL in this period, so I don't have a full knowledge for the moment. This was the best idea I had.

Comment: Take a look at the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` option to the `INSERT` statement. This allows you to do everything in one statement.

Answer (score 1):

Escape your user input!
`$temp = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['playername']);`

Make sure to stick your mysqli_connect() above that

```
$select = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT `id` FROM `mk7game` WHERE `playername` = '".$temp."'");
if(mysqli_num_rows($select))
    exit("A player with that name already exists");
```

Whack that in *before* the UPDATE query, and you should be good to go - obviously, you'll need to edit it to match your table setup